# jQuery Devbridge autocomplete - Force selection from list

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using DevBridge jQuery auto-complete, which is working fine but I want to force the user to select an option from the drop down list.

Is there any way to do this?

```
var airports = [
    { value: 'Manchester (MAN)' },
    { value: 'Bangkok (BKK)' }, 
    { value: 'New York (JFK)' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: airports
});
```

Comment: upvote, I too am looking for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

The function I've used is `onInvalidateSelection`

```
$("#MyField").autocomplete({
    onInvalidateSelection:function(){
        $("#MyField").val("");
    }
});
```

That's what worked best for me.

Comment: No this only works if user tries to change the selection after he/she selects an item. Still has option to write something that does not match the list and go on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

- I save the selected value on selected event to the HTML element attribute called "ac-selected-value".
- on focusout I check if the value is the same as that saved and if not clear the value

Now, I could not find a "mounted" or "initalized" event on this control (and I think they should add one) so I've changed the way I init the autocomplete - I do it via my own function that calls devBridgeAutocomplete and attaches a focusout listener:

```
$.MyNamespace.fs.autocomplete = function (elems, options) {
    elems.devbridgeAutocomplete(options);
    elems.focusout(function (e) {
        var txt = $(this);
        if (txt.attr("ac-selected-value") !== txt.val()) {                
            txt.val("");               
        }            
    });
};


...

// Set AC defaults:
$.Autocomplete.defaults.autoSelectFirst = true;
$.Autocomplete.defaults.onSelect = function (suggestion) {        
    $(this).attr("ac-selected-value", suggestion.value);   // stash a valid value here     
};
...  //  I also use this, but this alone will not get you far:
$.Autocomplete.defaults.onInvalidateSelection = function () {
    $(this).val("");
};
```

and then, somewhere down the line, you init a field like this:

```
$.MyNamespace.fs.autocomplete($("#select-something"), {
    serviceUrl: 'some-url'
});
```

and if on some elements you don't want to limit to list, you go classic:

```
$("#select-something").devbridgeAutocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'some-url'
});
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was in a similar situation.

I solved it using the API function `OnSearchComplete()`:

```
var temp_options;
$('#field').devbridgeAutocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '../index.php?eID=reportes&action=get_options',
    minChars: 3,
    onSearchComplete: function (query, suggestions) {
        temp_options = suggestions;
        if (!suggestions.length) {
            showInvalidOption();
        }
    },     
});
```

The function `showInvalidOption()` resets the field and shows a message to the user:

```
function showInvalidOption() {
    alert('Not valid option.');
    $('#field').val('');
}
```

This works. If the user entered a not valid option the field resets, but I found that if the input entered partially matches a word in the list (Ex: "Man" for "Manchester") and then changes focus to other field without selecting "Manchester" the word remains in the field, but it is invalid.

To solve this, I stored the options of the last search (I do the search via Ajax) in a temporal variable and then when validating the form I look if the word that remains in the field matches exactly one of the options.

```
var field = $('#field').val();
if (field) {
    var match = false;
    $.each(temp_options, function(key, option){
        if (option.value == field) {
            match = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (!match) showInvalidOption();
}
```

It is possible to refine the behavior to different situations but in general terms with this logic you prevent inputs not present in your list.